# Does gerrit code review support mailer lists

Tags: git, gerrit

As a part of code review i am planning to add a mailer list(which is a subset of many mail ids) to the reviewer list.

However it does not allow me to do so... any reasons as why it does not allow ?

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone can create group/mail-list in Gerrit. From the menu bar select *People* then *Create Group*. Even you can use the [CLI](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1.4/cmd-create-group.html) as well

```
ssh -p 29418 user@review.example.com gerrit create-group --member developer1 --member developer2 gerritdev
```

**Update:** you can invite users at pushing the change:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%r=<user>
```

or group after pushing the change:

```
ssh -p 29418 gerrit.example.com gerrit set-reviewers -a <group_name> Iac6b2ac2
```

Comment: Can we add that created group in the review ?

Comment: I got it..sorry ..i did figure to add it. when i add that user group.. gerrit expands the list and adds each individual...rather than the group..hence the confusion...